# android webkit opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, scroll

We are planning to change rendering of android webkit to OpenGL to improve scrolling/zooming performance. Is there any open source project which has already done that.
If not, can anyone sugggest any resources that would help us understand the scope of the problem